# SPARK Bucketing

Tags: apache-spark

- If my understanding is correct, one cannot bucket inline and then use this effect directly;

  - rather one must first write buckets and read back in again - if the source / target is not yet bucketed.

Seems odd in SPARK way of thinking. Or have I got it wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-bucketing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark bucketing is on-disk equivalent of partitioning (both organize data using specific key and hash partitioning) - if you want to "inline" the process, just `repartition` your `Dataset`

```
df.repartition(nPartitions, col)
```

Comment: That simple? I will check again